# GDataXML addchild

Tags: ios, xml, gdataxml

I have an XML file. Root is called *document*. *document* has several elements and nodes. In the middle, there are n number of *documentFile* elements. *documentFile* has some nodes. I would like to add 0 or more *documentFile* elements *right after the last occurrence* of *documentFile*

So I have something like:

```
<document>
   <someTags>
   <documentFile>
     <someSubTags>
   <documentFile> 
     <someSubTags>
   <someMoreTags>
</document>
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
GDataXMLDocument *tabsTree = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:tabsTreeData
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:nil];
GDataXMLElement *rootElement = [tabsTree rootElement];
[rootElement addObject:[self createGDataXMLElementForDocumentFile:tab]];
```

As expected, this adds *documentFile* element to the end of the XML.

I have also tried

```
  GDataXMLElement *rootElement = [tabsTree rootElement];
  GDataXMLElement *documentFile = (GDataXMLElement *) [rootElement
                                 elementsForName:kDocumentFile][0];
  [documentFile addChild:[self createGDataXMLElementForDocumentFile:tab]];
```

This adds the *documentFile* element as the child of the first occurrence of *documentFile*, which is not surprising either.

Comment: Have you figured this out already?

Comment: No but adding documentFile to the end of the XML did the job.